# Add a section header in ListView Menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu, sectionheader

I want to make a menu with some section headers.
But the source code in androidhive (http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) is not supported it.

So how to add a section header (or make a menu item to be a section header) without change the whole source code ? Please help me!

Here's the screenshot, i want to make the **"Lock"**, **"Unlock"** and **"Learn"** item to be the section header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk1zZ.png

Here's how I add item:

```
navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


    // adding nav drawer items to array

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8],0));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));       //, true, "22")); để thêm cái đuôi đằng sau

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9],0));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));       //, true, "50+"));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], 0));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();
```

UPDATE:

- I can't use Material Design due to some personal reasons
- What i need is Section Header. I did a "2 ListView in a Drawer and add Header in each ListView" but... yeah, it failed obviously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i got the answer!

Just add isEnabled() - false and change the layout at the specific positions in the adapter.

And my menu item changed to section header!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this library: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Here you can implement your navigation drawer in less than 5 minutes.

You can find there configurations for Activities with ActionBar, implement right and left menus etc.

The basic configuration is:

Gradle dependency:

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.0.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Add it to your Activity:

```
new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
```

For advanced settings, you can follow the readme or taking a look to the given examples.

I hope this would help you!

Comment: i actually did a Material Design NavigationView once. But now i can't use it!

 Any idea how to add Section Header without using Material Design?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a menu_layout XML layout that contains ListView.
Add this menu_layout XML layout in `DrawerLayout`.
Now populate your menu in ListView programmatically.
Now you can create a new header_layout XML.
Add this header_layout programmatically in header view of ListView using `addHeaderView()` method.

Comment: "Add this menu_layout XML layout in DrawerLayout" 

- Can you tell me how can i do that ?